# Filter and apply condition between multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
client_id   location_id      region_name    location_name
1                123          Florida        location_ABC
6                123          Florida(P)     location_ABC
6                845          Miami(P)       location_THE
1                386          Boston         location_WOP
6                386          Boston(P)      location_WOP
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- If some location_id has more than one client_id, I'll pick the client_id == 1.
- If some location_id has only one client_id, I'll pick whatever row it is.

If we were implementing only one logic, it should be as simple as `df[df['client_id'] == 1]`. But I can not figure out how to perform this type of filtering that requires verifying more rows at the same time (figure out how to check if some location_id has more then one client_id, for example).

So, in this scenario, the resulting data frame would be:

```
client_id   location_id      region_name    location_name
1                123          Florida        location_ABC
6                845          Miami(P)       location_THE
1                386          Boston         location_WOP
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with a custom groupby on the boolean Series equal to your preferred id, then slice:

```
out = df.loc[df['client_id'].eq(1).groupby(df['location_id'], wort=False).idxmax()]
```

output:

```
   client_id  location_id region_name location_name
0          1          123     Florida  location_ABC
2          6          845    Miami(P)  location_THE
3          1          386      Boston  location_WOP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.query("client_id==1") if len(dd)>1 else dd

df1.groupby('location_id').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

```
   client_id  location_id region_name location_name
0          1          123     Florida  location_ABC
1          1          386      Boston  location_WOP
2          6          845    Miami(P)  location_THE
```